# I'm transiting from Kuwait to Bahrain by car. What are the conditions of getting a Saudi Arabian transit visa?

Tags: visas, transit, saudi-arabia, kuwait, bahrain

Visa for Bahrain is now available online and on arrival. Do you still need to take Bahrain visa in advance to get transit visa for KSA? Does anyone know the telephone/mobile numbers for Waseet agents? Approximately how many days does it take to get KSA transit visa?

Comment: What's your country of citizenhip?

Answer (score 2):

Even I'm planning for road trip from Kuwait to Bahrain, yes you need to have Bahrain visa endorsed on your passport and then apply for Saudi transit visa through agents but right now Saudi transit visa are stopped temporarily due to hajj pilgrimage, I will be checking with jazeera agent after Eid holiday